# What's the difference of timestamp translation between pandas and time.strftime

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

I'am handling timestamp with pd.to_datetime(),i found the result is wrong?
then use time to deal with, get the different result.Which is the right result?

```
import time
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'times':'1571305233056'},index=['A'])
pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
A    2019-10-17 09:40:33
Name: times, dtype: object

def timestamp( times):
        time1=float(times/1000)
        timearray = time.localtime(time1)
        return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',timearray)

timestamp(int(df['times'])
'2019-10-17 17:40:33'
```

I expect the output is '2019-10-17 17:40:33'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because by default, you get the time in UTC. However, in the function you have converted that in your function with `localtime`
you can do that directly as below.

```
pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

The difference in values can be seen if you run the codes below

```
df=  pd.DataFrame({'times':'1571305233056'},index=['A'])
print(pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Europe/Berlin'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai'))
print(pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms').dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Shanghai').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

**Output**

```
A   2019-10-17 09:40:33.056
Name: times, dtype: datetime64[ns]
A   2019-10-17 15:10:33.056000+05:30
Name: times, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Kolkata]
A   2019-10-17 11:40:33.056000+02:00
Name: times, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
A   2019-10-17 17:40:33.056000+08:00
Name: times, dtype: datetime64[ns, Asia/Shanghai]
A    2019-10-17 17:40:33
Name: times, dtype: object
```

You can find the list of all time zones available with

```
import pytz
pytz.all_timezones
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because your second code converting the time to local time try using this but pd.to_datetime giving time in utc

```py
def timestamp( times):
        time1=float(times/1000)
        timearray = time.gmtime(time1)
        return time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%ST%Z',timearray)

timestamp(int(df['times']))
```

Or you can use df.tz_localize function to get local time in pandas

```py
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

df=pd.DataFrame({'times':'1571305233056'},index=['A'])
pd.to_datetime(df.times,unit='ms',).dt.tz_localize(dateutil.tz.tzlocal()).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%ST%Z')
```